# AlarmManager with flag AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY is executing in the current day, not in the next day

Tags: android, push-notification, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I need to add push notifications in my Android application. The notification must be shown every day at certain time (for example at 1 PM). To do this i am using an AlarmManager. I am registering an alarm, when the app is starting for the first time. But i  got a problem. 
If i am installing my application onto device, for example at 1.10 PM, then the alarm is running right after my app is started. But this is wrong, because I need this alarm to run in the next day, not in the current day. Can anyone help me and tell how to set **daily** alarm, that must start working on the day about from current day.

This is my code, which i am using for now

```
private void registerAMAlarmManger(){
    mAMAlarmIntent = new Intent(this, AMAlarmReceiver.class);
    mAMPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, mAMAlarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    SharedPreferences sPrefs = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int amTime = sPrefs.getInt(Constants.MORNING_TIME, 9);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, amTime);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, mAMPendingIntent);


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the time has passed for the current date it executes the code of performing alarm .This need to be handled . I do it by following way

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mytesthourofday);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,
                                Integer.parseInt(min_am_pm[0]));
                        // calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, am_pm_integer);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

                        if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                        }

alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                            calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 24 * 60 * 60,
                            pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would like to clarify about this part of code "if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                        }". Here you are checking if the alarm time is lower than current time and in this case you are adding one day to start alarm on the next day?

Comment: And one more question: calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()); Is this line of code necessary? Because in some tutorials about AlarmManager she is missing.

Comment: Yes i add one day .. I.e nxt day

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mytesthourofday);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,
                                Integer.parseInt(min_am_pm[0]));
                        // calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, am_pm_integer);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

                        if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                        }

alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                            calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 24 * 60 * 60,
                            pendingIntent);
```

Comment: explain your code so OP get more hint , Don't just post code